# Cmake Ctest check substring only

Tags: cmake, ctest

I have an issue with cmake ctest. I'm checking substring in the full string. But got the issue that the string is not found. How can I specify just looking for substring, but not full sting?

```
neg_message="App error: Error code=5"
set_tests_properties(test_app PROPERTIES
        FAIL_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "${neg_message}")

App error: Error code=5, Index=1, Line number=1389, aborting...
1/1 Test #1: test_neg_app ..............***Failed  Error regular expression found in output. Regex=[App error: Error code=5]  1.32 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

> FAIL_**REGULAR_EXPRESSION**

Match anything in front and after the message so the regular expression will match it.

> ```
> ... FAIL_REGULAR_EXPRESSION ".*${neg_message}.*")
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work: 
Test #1: test_neg_app ..............***Failed    0.99 sec

Answer (score 0):

This topic can be closed. I have to use PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION instead FAIL_REGULAR_EXPRESSION to check the expected substring. It works fine without extra commands.

Comment: I think you want to set `WILL_FAIL` _and_ `FAIL_REGULAR_EXPRESSION`

Comment: Unless your application returns 0 even on failure...

Comment: I have to use PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION and check the expected error message with the code.